# Laravel Redis queue handling

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io

I use Redis driver with Laravel to emit events to my NodeJS client, just sending event from some Laravel service or controller using `event()` helper method and listening on the client side by `socket io` and `NodeJS`.

I don't use any Laravel `Queues` and now I have the question:
What will happen if there will be many requests to the same `event()` method? Will Redis somehow handle it? Will it create some queue by itself and handle publishing events?

Thank you!

Comment: The events come across like `App\Events\MyEvent`. Jobs come across like: `App\Jobs\MyJob`. No interference. However, you can specificy the name of the queue to push onto / work.

Comment: So, there will be no impact?

Comment: Yep, no impact.

Comment: Queue is for situations when some action would take a long time e.g. 5sec, am I right?